# Manipulating data using ORM Sequelize / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am looking to make an async function/class method that will be able to go into my database of tasks and change all the "complete" values to true.

My model is called Task. I think I may be confused on what the model is because I am just trying to set

```
Task.complete = true;
```

which is not doing anything. How do I actually access and manipulate the data? I am making a class method.

```
Task.completeAll() = async function(){

 Task.complete = true;
}
```

I have been using the .findAll() method on the Task but I thought that would be used to just find data, not necessarily manipulate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use model methods such as **update**. For instance:

```
Task.update({ complete: true }, { })
```

If you wish to update only certain records just specify **where**  in an options object:

```
Task.update({ complete: true }, { where: {
  complete: false
}
})
```